# "None" al usar scraping una tabla de Wikipedia

Tags: python, scraping, scrap

les comento que he estado tratando de manipular una tabla de Wikipedia, específicamente una tabla con la lista de códigos postales de Canada.

He intentado usar el método scrapping (del cual estoy recién comenzando a usar) pero los códigos no me reconocen la tabla en cuestión. Como output me arroja `None`

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
table_class = 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'

response = requests.get(wiki_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

postal_codes = soup.find('table', class_ = 'table_class')
print(postal_codes)
```

Como les comenté me arroja `None`, siendo que la tabla si está en la [página](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M).

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me parece que la clase dentro de table, es "wikitable sortable" no 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'.

Y como defines esa class en la variable table_class, se deberia usar la variable en el metodo find, no usar un str, es decir quedaria algo asi:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'

#Aqui usar 'wikitable sortable'
table_class = 'wikitable sortable'

response = requests.get(wiki_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Aqui usar la variable table_class en vez de 'table_class'
postal_codes = soup.find('table', class_ = table_class)
print(postal_codes)
```

Comment: Funciona, mil gracias por la ayuda!!